# Returns 5th object and soon and make this as a long integer

Tags: mysql, function

I want to return the 5th character or in a id number.
Ex. I have id number PID-15, I want to return the query after the '-' so in this example 15 then make this a a integer or long integer. How can I achieve this? what particular  function that can make this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(id,'-',-1) from your_table;
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b621f/6)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

If you want to get this out of your table using SQL, take a look at the following functions that will help you: SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX. You can use those to trim your entries.

A possible query will look like this (where col is the name of the column that contains your image directories:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, LEN(SUBSTRING(col, 0, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX ('/', col))) + 1, LEN(col) - LEN(SUBSTRING(col, 0, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX ('/', col))) - LEN(SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX ('.', col), LEN(col))));
```